# Understanding the proof of Lemma 9.24(iii) in Rotman's group theory book

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, permutations

Lemma 9.24 (iii) of Rotman's book (p. 262f, fourth edition) "An Introduciton to the Theory of Groups" states the following:

> Let $k\geq 4$ and let $X$ be a $k$-transitive $G$-set of degree $n$. Let $H$ be a regular normal subgroup of $G$. Then $H\cong V_4$ and $n=4$.

($V_4$ is the Klein Four group, a regular normal subgroup is a normal subgroup which acts regularly, i.e. sharply transitive, on $X$).

The proof goes as follows:

We know from a pervious result that for $x\in X$, the stabilizer $G_x$ acts on $H^* = H\setminus \{1\}$ 3-transitively via conjugation. This means that $|H^*|\geq 3$, hence $|H|\geq 4$.

Since $H$ is a regular normal subgroup and $V_4$ acts regularly on $4$ symbols, $H$ must contain a copy of $V_4$ that we name $\{1,h,k,hk\}$.

Now $(G_x)_h$ acts 2-transitively on $H^*\setminus\{h\}$ via conjugation (because $G_x$ acts 3-transitively on $H^*$ via conjugation).

Rotman now claims:

> It is easy to see, however, that $\{k,hk\}$ is now a block,...

I tried to proof this statement and I don't know if my reasoning is correct. Let $B:=\{k,hk\}$ and $g\in G_{x,h} = (G_x)_h$. Suppose $B\cap gB \neq \emptyset$.

1. If $k\in gB$, then either $k = gkg^{-1}$ or $k = ghkg^{-1}$. In the first case, we then know that $hk = \underbrace{ghg^{-1}}_{=h}\underbrace{gkg^{-1}}_{=k}=ghkg^{-1}\in gB$. In the second case, $k = ghkg^{-1} = \underbrace{ghg^{-1}}_{=h}gkg^{-1} = hgkg^{-1}$. Since $h$ is an element of order two, we get $hk=gkg^{-1}\in gB$.
2. If $hk\in gB$, then either $hk=ghkg^{-1}$ or $hk = gkg^{-1}$. In the first case, we get $hk=ghg^{-1}gkg^{-1} = hgkg^{-1}$, i.e. $k = gkg^{-1}\in gB$. In the second case, we get $k = hhk = ghg^{-1}gkg^{-1}=ghkg^{-1}\in gB$.

This proves $B\subset gB$. To see the converse, let $w\in gB$. Since we already know that $B\subseteq gB$, if $w = gkg^{-1}$, then $w=k$ if $k=gkg^{-1}$ or $w=hk$ if $k=ghkg^{-1}$. The case $w = ghkg^{-1}$ follows the same way. Hence $B=gB$ and $B$ is a block.

I found this rather cumbersome and non-easy. Is my reasoning correct?
Is there maybe an even easier way of proving this (e.g. by using the double transitivity)?

Comment: Which edition of the book is it?

Comment: What is a "regular normal subgroup"? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @Shaun I've given the definition directly under the first quote...

Comment: Ah, yes, so it is; I read it as a property of $V_4$ for some reason. I'm sorry :)

Comment: Yes your reasoning is correct. It might be cumbersome, but it is straightforward, which is why Rotman has left it to the reader. You don't need to prove the reverse inclusion, because $|B| = |gB|=2$.

Comment: Note that, since $k$ is just an arbitrary symbol and $hk$ is just the product of that symbol with $k$ (i.e., $h(hk)=k$), you may assume that $k\in B\cap gB$. If $k^g=k$ then $g$ commutes with both $h$ and $k$, hence $(hk)^g=hk$ and $B=gB$. If $k^g=hk$ then $(hk)^g=h^gk^g=hk^g=h^2k=k$, so $B=gB$ again. This is what you stated, but slightly simplified.

Comment: @DerekHolt You're right! Thanks for your improvement!

Comment: @DavidA.Craven so you mean that the labels of the symbols are irrelevant because if $k\notin B\cap gB$, then we relabel $hk$ to be the "new" $k$, rewrite the other symbols in terms of our relabeling and proceed?

Comment: Exactly. We just chose one of the points to label by $k$. It could equally have been $hk$ that we labelled $k$, so the symmetry means we only have to consider $k$ in the intersection. (I proved this by noting that one obtains $hk$ from $k$ by multiplying by $h$, and the same holds for obtaining $k$ from $hk$.)

Comment: @DavidA.Craven perfect, thank you for your explanation!